# Shopify - Collections pagination on hompage

Tags: shopify

How can I integrate pagination to index.liquid page using the configured collection?

```
{% assign collection  = collections.collectionName %}
  {% paginate collection.products by settings.pagination_limit %}
   ...
```

So instead of collectionName I want to use the collection from theme settings (Themes / Home / Collection of products).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

And I just found it. If anybody has a same problem:

```
{% assign collection  = collections[settings.frontpage_collection] %}
```